# Page not found error for HTML code on site?

Tags: html

I recently started a personal portfolio but all the links don't work, even though I'm pretty sure I'm doing it exactly right. I get a page not found error every time that I click the link even though it's valid.

```html
<a href=”https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WWttMM2zCOVaXN0CPKfYzruyevwHUtsC/preview”>October 2020</a>
```

Comment: It's probably because you're using ” as a quote character instead of "

Comment: @PeterJ bingo. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix the quotes (`”` -> `"`)

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WWttMM2zCOVaXN0CPKfYzruyevwHUtsC/preview">October 2020</a>
```

Works for me.